# Load Data Local Infile into a truncated table, but it set Primary Key of the first row to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, load

I'm doing to migration from SQL Server on Windows into MariaDB on Linux. I exported data of one table from Windows into csv file and then imported the csv file into MariaDB with the following command:

```
mysql -h192.168.99.111 -P3306 -uUserID -pPass reports --init-command="set ?sql_mode='REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ANSI'; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" -e "Truncate table ReportDescr; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'ReportDescr.CSV'  INTO TABLE ReportDescr CHARACTER SET UTF8  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^^'  ESCAPED BY '' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\`' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (REPORTDESCRID,USERID,NAME,TITLE,ISTITLECONST,DESCRIPTION,DATASOURCETYPE,CATEGORY,UPDATETIME,DOMAINID,PUBLISHED,REPORTSET,REPORTKEY,RPTEXECUTABLE,PUBLISHSUBDOMAINS); "
```

The very first row of the CSV is inserted into MariaDB with the REPORTDESCRID being changed to 0. The other rows are inserted correctly.

The create table command for this table is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `reportdescr` (
`ReportDescrID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`UserID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
...
`rptExecutable` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ReportDescrID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `IX_ReportDescr` (`UserID`, `name`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have tried insert it by hand with command:

```
SET sql_mode='REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ANSI';
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
Truncate table ReportDescr;
Insert into table ReportDescr (REPORTDESCRID,...) VALUES (23,...)
```

and the ReportDescrId values is 23 as expected

As first I thought it was due to AUTO_INCREMENT, but I have checked and there's not AUTO_INCREMENT for Primary_Key ReportDescrID.

What's am I missing ? Why there is difference between the normal INSERT query and LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

Edit: Add a few row from CSV file:

```
 23^^`admin`^^`Automated Performance Analysis Report`^^`"Monthly Automated Performance Analysis Report for  "+1CustomerName`^^0^^`Monthly Automated Performance Analysis Reports`^^`Network`^^``^^2019-01-23 16:19:01.000^^0^^0^^`userdef`^^`-117,5,-1,0,28,39,101,-41`^^NULL^^0
 164^^`admin`^^`CPU Threshold Report with Counters`^^`"CPU Threshold Report for: "+1CustomerName`^^0^^`CPU threshold report. `^^`Network`^^``^^2019-01-29 11:16:52.000^^0^^0^^`userdef`^^`111,-87,76,-37,-71,101,51,27`^^NULL^^0
 163^^`admin`^^`Exception Count by Domain`^^``^^1^^`Monthly Performance Analysis Exception Counts`^^`Network`^^``^^2019-01-23 15:43:23.000^^0^^0^^`userdef`^^`12,93,-19,58,-125,-87,2,125`^^NULL^^0
 100^^`admin`^^`Inventory and Availability Report`^^`Inventory Report`^^1^^`Device inventory grouped by device type`^^`Network`^^``^^2012-03-01 15:49:13.000^^0^^1^^`userdef`^^`125,61,-27,-83,-80,-67,40,-79`^^NULL^^0
 0^^`admin`^^`Monthly Device Report`^^`"Monthly Device Report for "+1CustomerName`^^0^^`Standard Reports`^^`Network`^^``^^2019-01-23 15:44:05.000^^0^^0^^`userdef`^^`-41,-79,57,-28,66,-123,-31,-35`^^NULL^^0
 1^^`admin`^^`Monthly Traffic Report`^^`"Monthly Traffic Report for "+1CustomerName`^^0^^`Standard Reports`^^`Network`^^``^^2019-01-23 15:44:23.000^^0^^0^^`userdef`^^`116,66,107,-80,-115,107,-54,56`^^NULL^^0
```

Comment: 'Why there is difference between the normal INSERT query and LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.' - There isn't one. Have you tried running load data infile by hand from whatever ui you have or from mysql command line. Can you add first few rows of your csv file as text to the question.

Comment: It was originally run in a shell script file. But I have took it out and run loading data using mysql command line, they both give the same result. 
I did the same with Insert command on mysql command and the PrimaryKey of the first row wasn't changed to 0.

Comment: Looks like the 5th row is setting `ReportDescrID` to 0.

Comment: No, the real result is that the 5th row will not be inserted because the ReportDescrID  0 has already existed. I have tried removing the 5th row and still got the same result, ReportDescrID of the first row is always being turned to 0.